# Backlog Prioritization Issue

Tags: azure-devops

We have noticed that when we drag and drop items in priority order on a board, that same order is not shown if someone else opens that same board and has different column rows or has then ordered differently.

This is causing issues with the team understanding the next backlog item that needs to be picked up for grooming.

Does anyone have any ideas on how we can ensure the backlog order stays the same regardless of what order someone else's columns are in?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that when you are changing the order of work item, there is no others doing the same operation, which makes it to be reodered. To limit users' permission in this reagrd, please refer to [Default permissions and access levels for Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/permissions-access-boards?view=azure-devops).

At the same time, there might be some delay when you change the work item order. Also, please make sure your operation are valid, instead of a invalid change of  work item order due to your limit permission.